# h2o python H2ODataFrame apply raising error "ValueError: unimpl bytecode instr: LOAD_CONST"

Tags: h2o

Using `h2o python` api and have a H2ODataFrame that raises the error

> ValueError: unimpl bytecode instr: LOAD_CONST

when trying to use the apply method on the frame.

The frame in question here looks like:

```
predict     0_good      1_bad
0_NoDenial  0.999593    0.000407184
0_NoDenial  0.999571    0.000428798
0_NoDenial  0.998374    0.00162572
0_NoDenial  0.999343    0.000657361
0_NoDenial  0.999307    0.000693177
0_NoDenial  0.999895    0.000104678
0_NoDenial  0.999495    0.000504838
0_NoDenial  0.999627    0.000373012
0_NoDenial  0.997075    0.00292529
0_NoDenial  0.996358    0.00364194

<class 'h2o.frame.H2OFrame'>
```

The code that raises the error looks like:

```
preds['predict'] = preds['1_bad'].apply(lambda x: '1_bad' if x > custom_thresh else '0_good', axis=1)
```

With the full error looking like:

```
/home/mapr/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h2o/frame.pyc in apply(self, fun, axis)
   3034         assert_is_type(fun, FunctionType)
   3035         assert_satisfies(fun, fun.__name__ == "<lambda>")
-> 3036         res = lambda_to_expr(fun)
   3037         return H2OFrame._expr(expr=ExprNode("apply", self, 1 + (axis == 0), *res))
   3038 

/home/mapr/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h2o/astfun.pyc in lambda_to_expr(fun)
    133     code = fun.__code__
    134     lambda_dis = _disassemble_lambda(code)
--> 135     return _lambda_bytecode_to_ast(code, lambda_dis)
    136 
    137 def _lambda_bytecode_to_ast(co, ops):

/home/mapr/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h2o/astfun.pyc in _lambda_bytecode_to_ast(co, ops)
    147         body, s = _opcode_read_arg(s, ops, keys)
    148     else:
--> 149         raise ValueError("unimpl bytecode instr: " + instr)
    150     if s > 0:
    151         print("Dumping disassembled code: ")

ValueError: unimpl bytecode instr: LOAD_CONST
```

I've never seen this kind of error before and quick googling did not tell much more. Does anyone know why this is happening and what can be done about it? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

for this scenario you might just want to use the h2o `ifelse()` method

```
(preds['1_bad'] < .0005).ifelse('good','bad')
```

or if you create a new column that consists of your thresholds and append it to your original frame you could do

```
(preds['1_bad'] < preds['my_thresholds']).ifelse('good','bad')
```